# DbSet for Model classes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity Foo, with a corresponding Model class FooModel.

EntityFramework provides DbSet for storing my collection of Foo entities.

Question -- is there a corresponding built-in way to store my collection of FooModel objects? Or a standard practice for how to do it?

Comment: If you mean translating/mapping FooModel to Foo, and then storing Foo: there are many approaches for that, and a popular approach is named **AutoMapper**.

Comment: **Entity** Framework manages only **entity** instances. All other (models, view models, DTOs) are your responsibility.

Comment: Why would you store FooModel objects in the database too? FooModel objects *are* a projection of the Foo entities aren't they?